# Apply data-filter on page load

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a section on my site that is using `data-filter`'s. When the page is loaded all items show as default by the wordpress theme. At the top of the page there are four options to filter the items.

I am trying to make it so when the page loads one of the filters is executed as the default filter.

When I put this code into the console it works:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){    
  $('[data-filter=".dataplex-made"]').click()    
});
```

However, when I use a plugin the JQuery is not applying the filter.

Comment: try $('[data-filter=".dataplex-made"]').trigger( "click" );

Comment: what do you mean by "when I use a plugin the JQuery is not applying the filter."

Comment: can you please show your HTML for this?

Comment: @madalinivascu I have got a plugin which allows me to insert javascript code into the page, because pasting it normally is escaped (I believe).

Comment: @HarshSanghani `<a href="#" class="filter" data-filter=".dataplex-made">Dataplex Made</a>` if this HTML is clicked the filter is applied.

Comment: @Ish I tried your code and it did not work

Comment: what do you mean by escaped how is it escaped?

Comment: @madalinivascu you know how HTML code can be displayed, but not executed? It's similar

Comment: html code never executes html is a structured language, just remove that plugin and paste the code above in header.php

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @madalinivascu nothing is happening

Comment: any error in the console?

Comment: @madalinivascu No errors

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle with a working html code so i can test on it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('[data-filter=".dataplex-made"]').trigger( "click" );
});
```

Comment: I put the code here: dataplex.net.au, unfortunately it's not working